# Apache Beam Streaming from Kafka into Files over Fixed Window not working

Tags: python, apache-kafka, apache-beam

In python, I am trying to have a streaming pipeline that ingests data from Kafka, and then writes that data in 30 second intervals into a file at the end of each interval. I am using the FlinkRunner.

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
loaded_windowed_data = (
            pipeline
            | 'Read from kafka' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers, 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},topics=[input_topic])
            | 'Decode Kafka' >> beam.Map(lambda record: decode_kafka(record))
            | 'Fixed 30sec windows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(30))
            | 'Json Load' >> beam.ParDo(JsonLoad())
            | "PrintOutput" >> beam.ParDo(lambda c: print(c, type(c)))
            #| 'Write' >> WriteToText(output_path)
       
            )
```

The above code properly prints out the decoded json data. According to my understanding, a fixed window of 30 seconds should execute the my write/print. And the code as is does *print*. However, when I try to use the WriteToText class, I do not get any errors, but neither are my files written as desired.

I've also tried using a sink, as I've seen suggested by various posts:

```
class JsonSink(TextSink):
    def write(self, record):
      self._fh.write(json.dumps(record).encode('utf8'))
      self._fh.write('\n'.encode('utf8'))

loaded_windowed_data = (
    pipeline
    | 'Read from kafka' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers, 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},topics=[input_topic])
    | 'Decode Kafka' >> beam.Map(lambda record: decode_kafka(record))
    | 'Fixed 30sec windows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(30))
    | 'Json Load' >> beam.ParDo(JsonLoad())
    | 'Write Files' >> WriteToFiles(
                      path='./output',
                      #destination=lambda record: hash(record),
                      sink=lambda dest: JsonSink())
```

This snippet doesn't write either unless I replace 30 second fixed windows with the following:

```
loaded_windowed_data = (
    pipeline
    | 'Read from kafka' >> ReadFromKafka(consumer_config={'bootstrap.servers': bootstrap_servers, 'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},topics=[input_topic])
    | 'Decode Kafka' >> beam.Map(lambda record: decode_kafka(record))
    | 'Json Load' >> beam.ParDo(JsonLoad())
    | 'Fixed 30sec windows' >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(30))
    | 'Write Files' >> WriteToFiles(
                      path='./output',
                      #destination=lambda record: hash(record),
                      sink=lambda dest: JsonSink())
```

Even though this snippet *does* work, it seems to write about 60 text files in the output folder and then stops.

My question is what is the proper way to write a file streamed from Kafka? particularly, why doesn't the simple fixed window write every 30 seconds as desired? Do I need any particular window/trigger settings to get this to work as desire.

My code is largely based on this example provided by GCP:
https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-to-gcs

Comment: Did you set the PipelineOption `--streaming`?